# Volume returns 0 when called. Supposed to return 8

Tags: c++

Good morning! I have to do this for an exercise:

Since the Square and Cube geometric figures are drawn from points,
write a program that defines the Point, Square, and Cube classes.
Proceed using inheritance;

So I think I did well? Anyway, I hope...
However, there is a part that does not seem to work, the volume

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
using namespace std;
 
//########### Définition de la classe Point ###########
class Point {
    public:
        Point(int x, int y) {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
        }
 
        int getX() {
            return x;
        }
 
        int getY() {
            return y;
        }
 
    private:
        int x, y;
};
 
//########### Définition de la classe Carré ###########
class Square : public Point {
    public:
        Square(int x, int y, int side) : Point(x, y) {
            this->side = side;
        }
 
        int getArea() {
            return side * side;
        }
 
    private:
        int side;
};
 
 
//########### Définition de la classe Cube ###########
class Cube : public Square {
    public:
        Cube(int x, int y, int side) : Square(x, y, side) {
 
        }
 
        int getVolume() {
            return side * side * side;
        }
 
    private:
        int side;
};
 
 
int main() {
 
    Cube cube(1, 1, 2);
 
    cout << cube.getX() << endl; // 1
    cout << cube.getY() << endl; // 1 
    cout << cube.getArea() << endl; // 4 
    cout << cube.getVolume() << endl; // 8 
 
    return 0; 
}
```

But I don't know why it returns 0 in the volume :'c
It should be simple though! It's just an int of the side * side * side;

But when i run it it shows me
1
1
4
0

Why does this happend to the cube.getVolume()?

Comment: You never initialise `side` in `Cube`'s constuctor.

Comment: IMHO Not a great exercise for inheritance. Inheritance implies an “is-a” relationship. A square is not a point and a cube is not a square.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 3):

Your `Cube` subclass overrides the variable `side`. So you now have two "side" values: `Square::side` and `Cube::side`. The latter is never initialized.

If you were to simply remove `Cube::side`, then you have an access problem because `Square::side` is declared private. If you want `Cube` to access that member, it should be protected instead.

```
class Point {
    public:
        Point(int x, int y)
            : x(x)
            , y(y)
        { }
 
        int getX() const { return x; }
        int getY() const { return y; }
 
    protected:
        int x, y;
};

class Square : public Point {
    public:
        Square(int x, int y, int side)
           : Point(x, y)
           , side(side)
        { }
 
        int getArea() const { return side * side; }
 
    protected:
        int side;
};
 
class Cube : public Square {
    public:
        Cube(int x, int y, int side)
            : Square(x, y, side)
        { }
 
        int getVolume() const { return side * side * side; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that, since you have declared the variable `side` in `Square` class as `private`, `Cube` can not inherit from super class `Square`. So you can just assign the value of `side` in the constructor of `Cube`. Or make `side` of `Square` accessible to inherited class.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
using namespace std;
 
//########### Définition de la classe Point ###########
class Point {
    public:
        Point(int x, int y) {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
        }
 
        int getX() {
            return x;
        }
 
        int getY() {
            return y;
        }
 
    private:
        int x, y;
};
 
//########### Définition de la classe Carré ###########
class Square : public Point {
    public:
        Square(int x, int y, int side) : Point(x, y) {
            this->side = side;
        }
 
        int getArea() {
            return side * side;
        }
 
    private:
        int side;
};
 
 
//########### Définition de la classe Cube ###########
class Cube : public Square {
    public:
        Cube(int x, int y, int side) : Square(x, y, side) {
            this->side = side;
        }
 
        int getVolume() {
            return side * side * side;
        }
 
    private:
        int side;
};
 
 
int main() {
 
    Cube cube(1, 1, 2);
 
    cout << cube.getX() << endl; // 1
    cout << cube.getY() << endl; // 1 
    cout << cube.getArea() << endl; // 4 
    cout << cube.getVolume() << endl; // 8 
 
    return 0; 
}
```